# Как создать ванильный groupBy, чтобы он вернул массив объектов вместе с title?

Tags: javascript, массивы, group-by, map-reduce, obj

Есть функция, которая групирует массив объектов по ключу.
Наприме массив:

```
 data: [
    {
      CS_NAME: "AAA",
      IS_MAIN: "Y",
      WEBSITE_CREATE_DATE: "2021-06-01T15:50:37.687",
    },
    {
      CS_NAME: "AAA",
      IS_MAIN: "N",
      WEBSITE_CREATE_DATE: "2021-08-03T12:02:58.07",
    },
    {
      CS_NAME: "BBB",
      IS_MAIN: "Y",
      WEBSITE_CREATE_DATE: "2021-08-03T12:02:58.07",
    },
    {
      CS_NAME: "BBB",
      IS_MAIN: "N",
      WEBSITE_CREATE_DATE: "2019-01-26T00:00:00",
    },
    {
      CS_NAME: "CCC",
      IS_MAIN: "Y",
      WEBSITE_CREATE_DATE: "2019-01-26T00:00:00",
    },
  ]
```

Функция:

```
  groupBy(input, key) {
      return input.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
        let groupKey = currentValue[key];
        if (!acc[groupKey]) {
          acc[groupKey] = [];
        }
        acc[groupKey].push(currentValue);
        return acc;
      }, {});
    },

let obj = groupBy(data, "CS_NAME");
```

Как эту функцию изменить, чтобы она вернула массив объектов, у каждого  из которых  будет два поля:

```
{
   title: "CS_NAME" //( ключ по которому объекты групировались или любое другое свойство),
   content: {obj} //собственно сам объект целиком
}
```

К примеру:

```
{
  title: "AAA",
  content: [
    {
      CS_NAME: "AAA",
      IS_MAIN: "Y",
      WEBSITE_CREATE_DATE: "2021-06-01T15:50:37.687",
    },

    {
      CS_NAME: "AAA",
      IS_MAIN: "N",
      WEBSITE_CREATE_DATE: "2021-08-03T12:02:58.07",
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сдедать с помощью Object.entries

```
const groupBy = (input, key) => {
      return Object.entries(
        input.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
          let groupKey = currentValue[key];
          if (!acc[groupKey]) {
            acc[groupKey] = [];
          }
          acc[groupKey].push(currentValue);
          return acc;
        }, {})
      ).map(([title, content]) => ({ title, content }));
    };
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]